# why isEqualToString Gives unexpected result in ios5 with storyboard app?

Tags: iphone, ios5

```
 NSMutableArray *tempArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 if (self.subCategory) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.subCategory count]; i++) 
    {
        NSLog(@"subcat %@, detailItem %@",[[self.subCategory objectAtIndex:i]             valueForKey:@"id_cat"],self.detailItem);
        NSString *sub = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[self.subCategory objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"id_cat"]];
        NSLog(@"What the result is %@",([sub isEqualToString:self.detailItem] ? @"Yes" : @"No")); 
        if([sub isEqualToString:self.detailItem])
        {
            NSLog(@"obj of subcat %@",[self.subCategory objectAtIndex:i]);
            [tempArr addObject:[self.subCategory objectAtIndex:i]]; 
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"tempArr %@",tempArr);
```

Why this code every time gives this output

```
2012-03-20 15:50:26.156 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.157 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.158 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.158 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.159 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.160 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.160 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 2, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.161 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.162 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 2, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.163 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.163 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 3, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.164 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.165 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 4, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.165 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.174 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 5, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.176 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.176 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 6, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.177 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.177 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 3, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.178 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.178 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 7, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.179 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.180 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 8, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.180 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.181 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 9, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.181 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.182 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 4, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.182 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.186 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 5, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.186 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.187 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 6, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.188 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.188 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 7, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.189 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.190 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 8, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.190 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.191 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 9, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.191 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.192 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.193 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.193 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 2, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.194 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.195 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.195 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.196 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.196 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.197 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.198 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.198 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.199 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.200 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.200 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.201 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.201 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.202 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.202 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.203 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.204 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.204 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] subcat 1, detailItem 1
2012-03-20 15:50:26.205 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] What the result is No
2012-03-20 15:50:26.205 CameraFunWithFrames[1692:fb03] tempArr (
)
```

even if that shows subcat 1 and detailItem 1 both are nsstring but gives no if i compare them using isEqualToString function why??

what should i do to resolve this ?
i use xcode 4.3 and my application used storyboard instead of xib 
it works fine with xibs as i have used it before

Please help me 
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:: Got the solution thanks to you all who reply to this question thanks to you all

I put all data in plist file to type string as i need them as string before they are number specially the  id_cat key.
On conversion it give some unexpected results.

Comment: What is the type of detailItem? I mean its an object since you're logging with %@ but is it a string?

Comment: I tried running your code on my machine with the xcode 4.3 its working fine. May be some other ambiguity is there. Try debugging will solve your issue if you have done any mistake in the code.

Comment: @Alladinian detailItem is also nsString as i have already mentioned in  my question.  And all NSString data is also loged with %@ as i know

Comment: @Kuldeep i also try to debug it but it just west of time as nothing is  found. but thanks for your advice i will try it again thanks

Comment: Yes but NSNumber (and every object as a matter of fact) is also logged with %@, that's why I am asking...

Comment: Is it possible to show us the declaration of detailItem property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no technical reason why you'd get a different result using XIBs versus Storyboard, so I suspect a typo or some other small, unintentional change. Are there spaces at the end of `self.detailItem`? (When I use `NSLog` or thr debugger I always print a string such as `@"**%@**"` so I can see.)

Comment: thanks for advice i will try it an if i got something i will repost it

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Darlington i got the cause for it thanks too you

Comment: @AalokParikh: It would be good if you accept Stephen's answer so we know this issue is closed.

Comment: @rokjarc thanks for suggestion i will defiantly do it from now as i am new bee here